# Are these sets bounded or not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Definition:
A set $M \in R^n$ is bounded if there is a number C such that $|x| \leq C, \forall x \in M$.

Problem:
Determine if the following sets are bounded or not.

1) $\{ (x, y, z) : x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 1 \}$

2) $\{(x, y, z) : \sin(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) < 1\}$.

Comment:
I can't figure out why these sets aren't bounded. Is the first set a sphere or a coordinate? And for the second set, it seems to be bounded, since it only contains values in the interval $[-1, 1[$? The correct answer is that none of these sets are bounded, could someone explain to me why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the first is limited as it is a sphere. However, the second set is not, since e.g. the point $(\pi k, 0 ,0 )$ is in the set for every $k$

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 The first one is not a sphere (note the exponents). It is not limited, since $(n, -n, 1)$ is in the set for any $n$.

Comment: oh sorry, i read squares there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these sets is limited.

The first case may appear to be limited until we realize that we can use negative numbers as well - and then it becomes clear - we can take $(x,y,z)=(k,-k,1)$. This is included in the set since $k^3+(-k)^3+1^3=1$, but the magnitude $\sqrt{2k^2+1}$ grows without bound.

In the second case, we note that the $\sin(a)<1$ unless $a$ is in the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$. So we can just pick arbitrarily large $x$, $y$, and $z$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is not of this form and we are done. If you want an explicit set, we can choose $(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{n\pi},0,0)$. This is in the set since $\sin(n\pi+0+0)=0<1$, but the magnitude $\sqrt{n\pi}$ grows without bound (note here I mean for $n$ to be an integer).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help!